# simple SSIS help

Tags: sql, ssis, dts

i need to create a simple package that will:

1. insert a data to table A
2. get the scope_identity()
3. insert multiple rows to table B with the id from table A

i created one, but it only does bulk insert, so i want to redo it again.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You created "one" what? SSIS package? Table? Insert? I guess you could solve your problem using a "Lookup" component -- provided you are trying to solve the problem of "creating a foreign key relationship between table A and table B".

Comment: ssis package, I have a source & destination data flow component, i need to return the last identity from table A, how will i use the "Lookup" component from the destination component ?

Comment: similar to my problem, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/690772/in-an-ssis-package-how-do-you-insert-master-detail-records

Comment: it's just that there is something i'm not sure of "that grabs your source data and loads it into the variable (ADO.NET)."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, in this case I would probably not use a lookup but an "Execute SQL"-task.

You can have this execute an "arbitrary" SQL statement.Getting the last inserted identity value can be a bit tricky though. If you are not concerned about concurrent inserts not controlled by you a simple "MAX(...)" might do. Something along the lines of

```
SELECT max(<column_name>) FROM <A>
```

Otherwise it gets ab bit more involved. Look for an SQL statement that does what you want (this has nothing to do with SSIS, just with SQL). As I assume you are using MSSQL you might have a look at "[SQL SERVER – @@IDENTITY vs SCOPE_IDENTITY() vs IDENT_CURRENT – Retrieve Last Inserted Identity of Record](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)" for example.

Once you have your SQL plug it into an "Execute SQL" task and save its return value into a variable. See "[How to load a new table with the value of a variable from SSIS package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609862/how-to-load-a-new-table-with-the-value-of-a-variable-from-ssis-package)" for hints how to do this (sorry, I can't find a perfect example right now...). Maybe also either "[How to use OUTPUT parameters with SSIS Execute SQL Task](http://www.julian-kuiters.id.au/article.php/ssis-execute-sql-task-output-parameters)" or "[Technet - SSIS Execute SQL Task](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141003.aspx)".

And bear in mind: you do not "use `<whatever component>` *from* the destination component" but *before* it and store the result (here: current identity value) in a variable you can then use later.

Comment: Now, i used 2 "Execute SQL task" component, one for inserting to table A & one for getting the max(Id) (if i can make this on a single task, please let me know), now, for my 2nd problem, it seems it doesn't return the result set of the task back to variable.

Comment: From the result set tab of the task editor, i have set the alias column of my select statement equally to the task variable, but it seems nothing is happening. the variable remained 0.

Comment: Hmm - I guess you lost me here. What "alias column" do you mean? Does [How to use OUTPUT parameters with SSIS Execute SQL Task](http://www.julian-kuiters.id.au/article.php/ssis-execute-sql-task-output-parameters) not help? I know it's more about stored procedures but in the end you could put your query into a SP also (not the worst thing to do anyway...). If I remember correctly it boils down to first setting a property indicating that something is returned from the statement and then configuring where this something should go (variable).

Comment: I assumed the variable wasn't updated because I forgot to put a breakpoint on OnPostExecuted. now its working fine =), now, I need to pass the variable from Task A to Task B. Any ideas ? Thanks!

Comment: You can use your variable as an input variable to the second Execute SQL task. Maybe [The Execute SQL Task](http://www.sqlis.com/post/The-Execute-SQL-Task.aspx) can help? If not try your favorite internet search machine, I am pretty sure there is a tutorial somewhere. And by the way, I think having two tasks for inserting and getting max(id) is OK. You could most probably combine them (especially if you are using stored procedures) but you don't have to. You would then just put the two statements into the SP (or a query file read by the Exec.SQL task) and get the return value from the second

Comment: statement. As far as I remember this does not work if you are inputting the statement directly into the Exec.SQL GUI though.

Comment: i defined a variable called "globalID" on the package itself so it can be access by every component. i used SP on the first task to insert row and also to return an OUTPUT param, then passed it to my "globalID" variable, then used it to my second task w/c insert rows to details table , i also found this pretty neat tutorial about handling paramaters on sql statements http://www.rafael-salas.com/2007/11/ssis-mapping-parameter-inside-of.html

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I tried putting two statements (one insert statement & one IDENT_CURRENT) on a single task and it doesn't seem to work. so i think better approach is stored procs.

Comment: Appreciate the help, Thanks alot!